# Cannot resolve symbol errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
package com.example.kapsapp2021.register;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.kapsapp2021.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "RegisterActivity";

    @BindView(R.id.email)
    EditText email;
    @BindView(R.id.password)
    EditText password;
    @BindView(R.id.register_button)
    Button registerButton;
    @BindView(R.id.login_button)
    Button loginButton;
    @BindView(R.id.progress_bar)
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    @BindView(R.id.reset_button)
    Button resetButton;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);//using butterknife fot finding widgets
        //click R.layout.activity_signup press alt + enter to generate

        //firebase authentication instance
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, ResetActivity.class));
            }
        });

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RegisterActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });

        signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RegisterActivity.this.registerUser();
            }
        });

    }

    private void registerUser() {
        String userEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
        String userPassword = password.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail)) {
            showToast("Enter email address!");
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userPassword)){
            showToast("Enter Password!");
            return;
        }

        if(userPassword.length() < 6){
            showToast("Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters");
            return;
        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //register user
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail,userPassword)
                .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "New user registration: " + task.isSuccessful());

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            RegisterActivity.this.showToast("Authentication failed. " + task.getException());
                        } else {
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            RegisterActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void showToast(String toastText) {
        Toast.makeText(this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

This is the code I have right now in my RegisterActivity.java I watched some tutorials but I can't get whats going wrong. I get loads of 'cannot resolve symbol' errors, and I don't know how to solve that problem. I hope someone can help because I want to go further with this app I'm making :D!

Hope someone can help!

Kind Regards,
Sem

Comment: 1. The error messages will tell you *exactly* where the problems are and what is wrong, and you'd best read them critically. 2. If you're asking about such errors, it is also *extremely* wise to post all errors here in your question.

Comment: 3.  If you're seeing multiple compilation errors, then this suggests that your style of coding needs to be fixed. Don't type a large amount of code and then test it. Instead, if you can't use a modern IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse (which warns you of compilation issues almost immediately), then it is up to you to compile your code **early and often**, and most importantly **to not add any new code until current compilation issues are fixed**. Else you'll end up with a rat's nest of hard to fix errors.